# How to remove remnant edges/vertices from a multi-cube mesh?

Tags: mesh

How would you remove the edges/vertices inside each cube of this object and make it truly a single mesh?

[image]

Comment: Have you tried the boolean modifier?

Comment: I tried that but I need to use another mesh to apply the boolean to and my meshes are different cubes/rectangles joined together into a mesh.

Does the boolean works while in edit mode? Tried using the drop pick onto a vertice in edit mode but didn't seem to select anything.

Thanks!

Comment: See if this helps https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/50351/how-can-i-delete-internal-vertices-faces-and-edges

Comment: That totally did it. Thank you very much Sir!

Made it a shortcut as is real fast to work with.