# Fast way to remove internal faces for multiple objects at once

Tags: modifiers, 3d-printing

I have some blends which have multiple objects and I want to turn them all in to one object with no internal faces for 3D printing. Currently I have been repeatedly applying a boolean modifier but this takes a lot of time as it has to be done for every single object I want to join. Is there any fast way to select all of the objects and get the same result as a union boolean modifier?

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/43150/removing-internal-geometry-before-3d-printing and https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/50351/how-can-i-delete-internal-vertices-faces-and-edges and https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/71687/removing-internal-geometry

Answer (score -1):

Does a Ctrl + J to join the meshs is what you ask ? Otherwise I don't have an answer. Maybe you should take a look at the add-ons, I think there is one with the booleans, but I don't remember its name, but I think it isn't on Blender by default.

Comment: Note that Ctrl+J joins multiple objects into one object with multiple meshes; it doesn't edit geometry of meshes inside object datablocks in any way which is what OP would like to do