# Remove all internal geometry in complex mesh?

Tags: modifiers

I have around 9 complex meshes and would like to join them all and remove all the internal geometry so that I can 3D print them. I separated by loose and then used ctrl shift + with booltool. This worked for the most part, except there are still some pieces that didn't connect. Is there any way for me to get just the outside of the mesh? (I tried carving it into a box with booltool which seems like a good idea to me but didn't work for some reason?)

Comment: [This question](https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/121721/935) has links to several related questions in its comment.