# How do I delete vertices that clip inside a mesh?

Tags: modifiers

I'm trying to merge the sculpt of this head together with this body.

I used a boolean modifier, applied it, and saved my work. I didn't realize until later that the mesh is still visible on the inside. I can no longer select linked with ctrl + L to separate the head from the body to start over, as it selects both the head and the body.

[image: Vertices showing though.]

I did some research and found [this](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/50351/how-can-i-delete-internal-vertices-faces-and-edges). I tried to use Faces > Intersect (boolean), with no results. Instead, I see a message on the bottom right of Blender saying "no intersections found".

[image: Performing a union boolean intersect]

How do I get rid of the vertices from the head sculpt that clip through the body sculpt? Thanks in advance!

UPDATE: I guess what I'm trying to ask is why isn't it letting me select linked?

The vertices here aren't merged, but whenever I press L to select linked, *everything* is selected.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

What you want is do remove anything that goes inside your torso part , you can duplicate your head , if your head is a part of your torso but if it is a separate object in the edit mode you can select one face on the head and do <kbd>CTRL+L</kbd> to select the linked faces ,if you didnot merge any vertices of the head with the torso , this will work, and use one of the head to bool out(difference) the torso and then your second head will fit perfectly

Comment: How do I duplicate the head if I can't select the head alone with Select > Select Linked?

Comment: @MEATTAIL edited the awnsere